# Send a new list to the result of the LINQ query from the list for C#

Tags: c#, linq, generics, generic-list

I'm creating a generic list from the Class I've created and entering my required data.

```
    public class GroupList
    {
        public int pertt { get; set; }
        public int pips { get; set; }
        public int[] iVals;

        public GroupList(int PerTT , int Pips , int[] iValues)
        {
            this.pertt = PerTT;
            this.pips = Pips;
            iVals = iValues;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"PerTT: {pertt} Pips: {pips} Values: {string.Join(", ", iVals)}";
        }
    }
```

I want to enter my data into my mydatalist list derived from this Class and send the LINQ query to the Mylinqresult Generic list and print it correctly and perform mathematical operations.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<GroupList> myDataList = new List<GroupList>
    {
        new GroupList(15, 65, new[] {3, 9, 21, 1, 56}),
        new GroupList(15, 65, new[] {13, 19, 121, 11, 156}),
        new GroupList(10, 19, new[] {23, 29, 221, 12, 562}),
        new GroupList(10, 21, new[] {33, 93, 213, 13, 356}),
        new GroupList(21, 9, new[] {43, 49, 421, 41, 456}),
        new GroupList(21, 19, new[] {35, 95, 216, 17, 56})
    };

    List<GroupList> myLinqResult = new List<GroupList>();
    myLinqResult = from x in myDataList
                   where x.iVals[] >  65
                   select x;
}
```

I get a compile error when I type the query in this way.

The query can be queried based on the parameters given in the Int32 Array and can be accessed by sending the results to the same format list to print and perform mathematical operations with the data.

Comment: "I get a compile error when I type the query in this way." -> and the error is...?

Comment: You can't access an item of an array without specifying an index: `where x.iVals[] >  65` will fail.

Comment: Your LINQ expression (`from x in ... select x;`) does not return a `List<T>`, it returns a LINQ-ish `IEnumerable<T>`.  If you take the whole expression, wrap it in parentheses, and then call `.ToList()` on it, you will get a List.  Oh, and when you say "I get a compile error", it would be really nice for you to say "I get this compiler error".  They are easy to copy from the Output pane of VS

Comment: CS0443 Syntax error; value expected

Comment: What are you trying to select? All `GroupList` objects that have any item in their array that's over 65? Or all the items from all the `GroupList` objects that are over 65? Or something else?

Comment: That would be on the `where x.iVals[] >  65`, I'm assuming.  What are you trying to say with that expression.  What aspect of that array are you trying to test for greater-than-65-ness?  The length, the maximum value, the first element?

Comment: Oh, and even if you get that LINQ expression to return a list, you don't need to initialize the variable this way: `List<GroupList> myLinqResult = new List<GroupList>();`  You are constructing a list only to throw it away.  The `var` keyword is great for working with LINQ stuff.  Consider getting rid of your original declaration and just use: `var myLinqResult = (from x ... select x).ToList();`

Comment: x.iVals[] >  65 ten büyük olanlardan oluşan yeni bir liste oluşturmak istiyorum.

örnek olarak.
              1)  myDataList.Add(new GroupList(15, 65, new int[] { 3, 9, 21, 1, 56 }));
              2) myDataList.Add(new GroupList(15, 65, new int[] { 13, 19, 121, 11, 156 }));


myLinqResult = 2)    15,65 , {121,156}

Comment: X. ivals [] > > I would like to create a new list of the larger than 65. As an example. 1) mydatalist. ADD (New Grouplist (15, 65, new int [] {3, 9, 21, 1, 56})); 2) mydatalist. ADD (New Grouplist (15, 65, new int [] {13, 19, 121, 11, 156})); Mylinqresult = 2) 15.65, {121.156}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to select all the `GroupList` objects that have an item in their array that's over 65, you can do:

```
List<GroupList> myLinqResult = myDataList
    .Where(item => item.iVals.Any(i => i > 65))
    .ToList();
```

Otherwise, if you're trying to select all items that are over 65 (regardless of which `GroupList` they belong to), you can do:

```
List<int> allItemsOver65 = myDataList
    .SelectMany(item => item.iVals)
    .Where(i => i > 65)
    .ToList();
```

And finally, if you want to select **new** `GroupList` items that match the originals but only contain items in their `iVal` arrays that are over 65, you could do something like:

```
List<GroupList> myLinqResult = myDataList
    .Where(item => item.iVals.Any(i => i > 65))
    .Select(item => 
        new GroupList(item.pertt, item.pips, item.iVals.Where(i => i > 65).ToArray()))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but that's not the answer I want.

           myDataList 
             1 -   15,65, {5,16,59,65,150   }           
             2 -   15,65, {9,16,39,59,11         }
             3 -   10,19, {21,56,69,110,121,156 }
             4 -   15,65, {1,3,19,56,72,110,89    }

           LinqResults 
             1 -   15,65, { 150    }           
             3 -   10,19, { 110,121,156  }
             4 -   15,65, { 72,110,89  }

Comment: Ok. Please update your question to include the desired output. That way it's readable and discoverable by everyone.

Comment: Also, if you want to include code in your comments, surround it by the tick character (`)

Comment: I've tried the new saw and tried it smoothly.
Thank you very much. @rufus